# Windows VAMT 2 not showing keys remaining activation count

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, licensing

I manage a test network consisting in a dozen windows server (mostly 2008r2). All the servers use MAK keys (from MSDN or technet). I have recently decided to start using Volume Activation Management Tool 2.0 instead of putting keys manually on each server, but I have run into a catch.

The remote key deploiement and activation parts of the tool work well. However, the key management system is unable to show me the remaining activation count of my MAKs. The keys are recognized fine (right key type and product), but when I click on "refresh product key data online", a popup window with a progress bar appears briefly, then disappears and nothing changes, the "remaining activation count" field staying at `"<not available>`".

The server on which VAMT 2.0 is installed is a fully activated Windows 2008 R2 (therefore x64). It has full connectivity to the Internet without any proxies, but with a NAT box (with all outbound traffic allowed). It is a virtual machine running on Hyper-V. It is fully patched. It is member of a domain. An installation of VAMT on another 2008r2 VM (same domain) changed nothing, nor dit it on a Windows 7 x64 physical box (no domain, same natbox for internet connection).

I have done a quick search that has only shown me that it should work, MAK from MSDN being specifically mentionned inside MS doc. The same problem seems to be mentionned [here](http://boardreader.com/thread/VAMT_2_0_Doesnt_Show_Remaining_Activatio_1sr7b__dcb29f9d-0e5c-4b75-91bb-97cfc73e99e2.html) or [there] win7heads.com/installation/81388-vamt-2-0-doesnt-show-remaining-activation-count.html but without any solution.

It seems so stupid a problem I'm sure I'm missing the obvious. So would anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was actually given on the [technet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/dcb29f9d-0e5c-4b75-91bb-97cfc73e99e2). I take no credit for it, but here it is in case someone stumbles upon the question looking for the solution: VAMT 2 activations count only works with English locale. And I was using another language. I've just switched my server to English and it works perfectly now.

No comment on the quality of the tool ;-)